# Intellij invoke complete statement equivalent in sublime text

Tags: intellij-idea, sublimetext2

There is a very useful keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ which consist of completing a statement. This shortcut is `ctrl+shift+enter`. Examples of this feature can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/completing-statements.html).
How can I use this feature in sublime text 2? Or is it a missing feature?

Comment: example of such completion?